# GDCL Mp4mux filter BeginFlush() is a one-shot operation. Can I work around this limitation?

Tags: c++, mp4, directshow

Our transcoding/DSP project is consuming multiple-programme MPEG2-TS streams as input.

The transcoding branch endpoint of our DirectShow graph is an instance of the **GDCL Mpeg4Mux** filter.

The elementary streams ***may change PID values on the fly*** (I don't know the reason for this, but it happens).

In order to respond to these dynamic changes, we are parsing the PSI output from the MPEG-2 demuxer, and we instruct the demuxer to remap the output pins' PID values on the fly.  **Whenever this happens, the demuxer triggers a `BeginFlush()` call on the downstream sub-graph.**

Now, here is the implementation of `MuxInput::BeginFlush()` and `MuxInput::EndFlush()` methods  (`MuxInput` being the Input pin class for the `Mpeg4Mux` filter):

```
STDMETHODIMP 
MuxInput::BeginFlush()
{
    #if defined(ALAXINFODIRECTSHOWSPY_AVAILABLE)
        if(m_pMediaSampleTrace)
            m_pMediaSampleTrace->RegisterComment((IBaseFilter*) m_pFilter, (USHORT*) Name(), (USHORT*) L"Begin Flush", 0);
    #endif // defined(ALAXINFODIRECTSHOWSPY_AVAILABLE)

    // ensure no more data accepted, and queued
    // data is discarded, so no threads are blocking
    if (m_pTrack)
    {
        m_pTrack->Stop(true);
    }
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP 
MuxInput::EndFlush()
{
    #if defined(ALAXINFODIRECTSHOWSPY_AVAILABLE)
        if(m_pMediaSampleTrace)
            m_pMediaSampleTrace->RegisterComment((IBaseFilter*) m_pFilter, (USHORT*) Name(), (USHORT*) L"End Flush", 0);
    #endif // defined(ALAXINFODIRECTSHOWSPY_AVAILABLE)

    // we don't re-enable writing -- we support only
    // one contiguous sequence in a file.
    return S_OK;
}
```

As you can see, flushing is a one-shot operation because `EndFlush()` does not support resuming output writing on the track.
Unfortunately, once the PIDs are remapped,  the muxer silently rejects any further input. Debugging shows it is rejecting the samples because it is in a "Stopped" internal state.

Now, I could probably augment  the Muxer interface in order to provide a notification method that advises the filter that an impending PID is coming and that it should ignore the next flush call, **but I fear I might create a deadlock, since media samples could be held by the filter and the flush operation is supposed to release any locks and release any held samples.**

**Also, how should I react to the case where the demuxer is resetting its internal state and forcing a downstream flush?**